# I can use amazon cognito to controll access roles in my application web?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Can I control access to specific resources in my web application with amazon Cognito?

I would like when performing a Rest authentication to return the specific permissions of which resource of my web application the user can use as: createClient, updateClient, deleteClient, createUser, updateUser, deleteUser.

Can anyone help me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do. You can use role based access control or AWS Lambda Authorizer for this

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/navigating-gdpr-compliance/control-access-to-web-applications-and-mobile-apps.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/evaluating-access-control-methods-to-secure-amazon-api-gateway-apis/